# Dovecot allow certain users to authenticate from Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, dovecot

I am setting up the dovecot-ldap, and able to authenticate against Active Directory. However I would like to restrict only certain user able to login.

dovecot-ldap.conf

```
hosts = x.x.x.x
base = dc=xxxx,dc=local
ldap_version = 3
dn = xxxx/administrator
dnpass = xxxx
auth_bind = yes
auth_bind_userdn = %u
user_attrs = sAMAccountName=user
user_filter = (&(ObjectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=mail1))
```

I want to restrict only user "mail1" is able to login.

Apparently it does not work. I am still able to login using user "mail2"

I could have thousand of user from Active Directory, however my end goal is to only allow user "mail1" to be able to login, all other users should not be able to login

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the tag states, QUESTIONS ABOUT POSTFIX ADMINISTRATION ARE OFF-TOPIC.

Answer (score 0):

best I could find was https://wiki.dovecot.org/Authentication/RestrictAccess:

> Just like with SQL, you can use %s in pass_filter, eg.:
>
> ```
> pass_filter = (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=%u)(service=%s))
> ```
>
> That would require setting both service=pop3 and service=imap
> attributes to the user objects.

the additional **(service=%s)** instruction prevents any form of access (imap,pop,smtp,...) to any user without "service" explicitly defined. Instead of "service", you can use any attribute  at your convenience, just make sure it contains the service you intend to make availabe to the special user you are talking about.